# Dynamically add form to formset in Django and submit with AJAX

Tags: ajax, django, django-forms

I have read a lot of answers relating to how to dynamically add forms to an model formset in Django and can successfully implement that. However, I would now like to submit the formset with AJAX. This is mostly working now but I have an issue that I can't find a solution to in any other answer:

If you dynamically add a form to the formset, you give it a new form id number that is one larger than the maximum the form currently has and you also increment the management TOTAL_FORMS count by one. The newly added form then saves successfully as a new object.

I am trying to submit by AJAX so the user can continue editing without having the page refresh. The formset saves fine but any dynamically added forms are now existing objects. To account for this I need to increment the INITIAL_FORMS count on the management form when the save is successful. Easy enough. However, I've also realised I need to give the newly created objects an ID since they now exist in the database.

How can I get my view to tell me the ID of the new objects in its response to the AJAX call? Or is there a better way of looking at this?

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/madzohan/ato/src/38039ba2ee5473ea30585fdaa183bbf837e23129/apps/common/static/common/js/formsetAddForm.js?at=master

Comment: But, tell me if my thoughts are wrong, if you use AJAX, you don't need a formset, because you only submit one form.. And now read the whole question. My question to you, what does your view return? I would make it `JSON`?

Comment: Thanks for reply but I don't think this solves my problem. It just adds a new form to the formset no?

Comment: Yes view returns JSON. At the moment it just returns either a little bit of code to confirm the validation was successful or an array of the errors applicable to the forms.

Comment: But I need it to somehow return the ID of newly created objects

Comment: Use this front end plugin: https://github.com/elo80ka/django-dynamic-formset. I personally use it and works well.

Comment: I haven't read through fully but after a quick glance that looks like its to do with adding and deleting forms from formset (which I can already do) and nothing to do with AJAX submission (which is where my problem is)

Comment: So getting this straight, you want: 1) to dynamically add and remove items using some javascript, and 2) save all items at once using AJAX, then keep editing the item list. Right? So your issue is ensuring newly added items do not get added again the second time the user pushes save?

Comment: @spectras Yes exactly

Answer (score 2):

Django forms and formsets are intended for classic browser-based posting of data. Though they can definitely be made to work with Javascript, the more you want to part from the normal behavior, the more complex it gets.

Depending on your requirements, you might start thinking about dropping it and switch to Javascript + REST endpoint. Of course, if you need progressive enhancements and you are required to have it work without javascript, that's not an option.

In any case, you want to have a customized view for posting from JS, so that you can get the result back and parse it easily in your AJAX handler. Probably some JSON.

There are several approaches you could take.

- Have your AJAX send data to a different URL. This is pertinent if you have an API or are planning to build one at some point. So your form, when submitted normally, will do its old-style processing but your AJAX will talk to the API endpoint instead.

  For instance, your form send to `https://example.com/myform`, but your Javascript code talks to REST api at `https://example.com/api/v1/mymodel/` (sending PUT, POST and DELETE requests as appropriate).
- Or if you don't have an API and building one seems overkill, you may just alter your view so it formats its output differently depending on whether the data is being submitted in the regular way or using AJAX.

  You'd go about it like this:

  ```
  class MyFormView(.....):
      def render_to_response(self, context, **kwargs):
          if self.request.is_ajax():
              return self.render_to_json(context, **kwargs)
          return super().render_to_response(context, **kwargs)

      def render_to_json(context, **kwargs):
          data = {
              # see below!
          }
          return HttpResponse(
              content=json.dumps(data).encode('ascii'),
              content_type='application/json',
          )
  ```

  This is just an outline. You need to ensure `is_ajax` will detect it properly (see [django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.is_ajax)). And you need to properly build `data` from `context`: extract the things you want to send back to your JS code and put them in the dict.

  You will find it's manageable if you just do this for one, maybe two views in your project, but very quickly you'll want to have a small API instead, especially given how easy it is to build one with packages such as [Django REST framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/).

Answer (score 0):

In your view, where you save the object, AFTER the save, the object.id will contain the new id for the object, which you can return via json or however you want in your ajax response, and then yes you will need to fill that into the formset row so that it will be submitted the next time.

One thing you have to watch out for is that django expects all existing rows to be at the top of the formset, and any new rows to be at the bottom.  Otherwise, the formset save will complain about missing id's.  So if you're doing any kind of sorting in your javascript, you can't do that.. unless you do quite a bit of fixing of all the field names etc in the formset.  The formset code uses the numbers in the management form to determine which rows to insert and which rows to update, it does not do it on the basis of whether or not an id is present.  Unfortunately...